# How to use case replacement pattern with Xpath replace function

Tags: xslt, xpath, regexp-replace

I have this [regexp and substitution patterns demo](https://regex101.com/r/nYjafA/2/) and need to use it within an xpath context with the fn:replace function,but I can't figure out how to write the replacement string correctly Is it possible ? 
my naive test was

```
replace ("dsfjkljsdfjlsjdfABCDdfsfsdff",
             "(\p{Lu})(\p{Lu}+)",
             "$1\L$2")
```

but it complains with FORX0004 : Invalid replacement string in replace() : \ character must be followed by \ or $

Comment: Can you explain in plain English which replacement you want to perform? Also consider to include the relevant samples in the question text. Note that within XSLT 2 and later you have user defined functions and `xsl:analyze-string` to "implement" anything with regular expressions the XPath 2 `replace` might not give you, so if you want to apply a string function to the part of the match I think you should look at that option.

Comment: the purpose is to detect sequence of contiguous UPPERCASE characters within a word and to transform it to Uppercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want e.g.

```
<xsl:function name="mf:lower-case-match">
  <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:param name="regex" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:analyze-string select="$input" regex="{$regex}">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(regex-group(1), lower-case(regex-group(2)))"/>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:function>

mf:lower-case-match("dsfjkljsdfjlsjdfABCDdfsfsdff", "(\p{Lu})(\p{Lu}+)")
```

or, to use the `as="xs:string"` as the declared function type:

```
<xsl:function name="mf:lower-case-match" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:param name="regex" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:value-of>
      <xsl:analyze-string select="$input" regex="{$regex}">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(regex-group(1), lower-case(regex-group(2)))"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>          
  </xsl:value-of>
</xsl:function>
```

You need to declare a namespace for any user-defined function e.g. `xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform` root.

In XSLT 3 you could also simply push the result of the `analyze-string` function through a mode that then performs any transformation on the groups you want:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="text">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., '(\p{Lu})(\p{Lu}+)')" mode="lower-case"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*:group[@nr = 2]" mode="lower-case">
      <xsl:value-of select="lower-case(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Martin. It seems almost good, except that when I run the transformation, it complains when calling on the call to the function with following message : XTTE0780 A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the result of a call to mf:lower-case-match

Comment: I also try repalcing xsl:value-of with xsl:sequence but get the same message

Comment: For a quick fix , remove the as attribute from the function declaration. I will try to test later whether wrapping the function body into value-of fixes the type problem.

Comment: see it live at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFK9t

Comment: I would be very intrested by the general solution of transforming any "regex-oriented" issue with this method of "wrapping into function"

Comment: so when removing result type declaration as=xs:string, it actually works, but then xsl:value-of produce the correct input, whereas xsl:sequence introduces spaces between each "substring"

Comment: @MysticTm, see the edit, in this case, to "follow" the good coding practice to declare the function's return type the body needs to be a bit more complicated using an `xsl:value-of` wrapper element around the `xsl:analyze-string`.

Comment: I made a new version https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFK9t/1 and you can see that even if removing the return type attribute as="xs:string" to the function, it stil fails when trying to assigned to an intermediate variable with the same type attribute as="xs:string", so the workaround is not fully functional.

Comment: a solution should consist of "piping" the call to fm:lower-case-match with fn:string-join(.,'') so that it concatenate all substrings (matchings / non matchings) together, but I don't like it very much : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFK9t/2

Comment: @MysticTm, see the value-of wrapper suggestion or use your approach with `string-join` by putting the `xsl:analyze-string` into a variable and then return the call of `string-join($var)` from the function (you can even use `xsl:sequence` then).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `\L` regex property is supported with XPath. @Martin Honnen's answer is probably the best, but here's a full XPath 2.0 solution :

With :

```
dsfjkljsdfjlsjdfABCDdfsfsdff
```

XPath :

```
replace(replace("dsfjkljsdfjlsjdfABCDdfsfsdff","(\p{Lu})(\p{Lu}+)","$1___$2___"),"_{3}.+_{3}",lower-case(substring-before(substring-after(replace("dsfjkljsdfjlsjdfABCDdfsfsdff","(\p{Lu})(\p{Lu}+)","$1___$2___"),"___"),"___")))
```

Description :

P1 : We add `___` to identify the lower-case part with :

```
replace("dsfjkljsdfjlsjdfABCDdfsfsdff","(\p{Lu})(\p{Lu}+)","$1___$2___")
```

P2 : We generate the lower case part with :

```
lower-case(substring-before(substring-after(resultofP1,"___"),"___"))
```

We join the two preceding expressions with :

```
replace(resultofP1,"_{3}.+_{3}",resultofP2)
```

Output :

```
dsfjkljsdfjlsjdfAbcddfsfsdff
```